# In python. class variable is static..is I want to use different instance. is there any solution?

Tags: python

In python, I want to make a class variable static so I can to use it from a different instance. is there any solution?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Comment: @alpha: From the reply to my post, it appears that it's the exact opposite question :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't follow your question exactly, but it seems to me you're asking how to make instance variables in Python. The answer is to set them inside a method, preferably `__init__()` using the `self` reference.

```
class Foo(object):
    classVar = 0 #this is a class variable. It is shared between all instances
    def __init__(self, instanceVar):
        self.someVar = instanceVar

obj1 = Foo(10)
obj2 = Foo(42)

print obj1.classVar # prints 0
print obj2.classVar # prints 0

print obj1.someVar #prints 10
print obj2.someVar #prints 42
```